# Looking for Google Map or similar GIS alternative to impose my village map and track my live and land parcel location

Tags: qgis-3, openstreetmap, google-maps, google-earth

I had a non Georeferenced shapefile of a village and then I Georeferenced it with Georeference tool of QGIS 3.32 by properly imposing it above Google Hybrid Base Layer. Then I exported to KML so that I can see village map with parcel numbers in Google Earth.

But I want to know if in Google Map or any similar GIS alternative, I can impose my village map such that my current live location (start) and destination location (any parcel of the village) can be traced so that I can know how far I am from that parcel and track my movement as I move towards or far from that land parcel.

Comment: qgis2web [plugin] will do this https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2web/

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for a mobile app, try [Organic Maps](https://organicmaps.app/).

If you want a simple web GIS app, try [uMap](https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/).

Comment: I searched over net. There is GEOJSON file that can be overlaid on a google map ? Do you have any idea about it.

Comment: uMap supports geojson.